# Tizen app not installable on TV Firmware 1422

Tags: tizen

We are developing a new Tizen Web App for one of our products. It was working all well until last week to the moment, we updated our TV.

Now our TV is running on Samsung Software "1422" - and the App is not installable anymore. This seems promising for the future of tizen developement, good job samsung :-P

Now we updated everything in our SDK to the latest version 2.4 - and we've rebuilt the application with all the new tools.

It is still not working. We totally don't understand - nothing changed on the App. I can still build everything with 2.4.

But even with the Emulator of Release 2.4 it is not working anymore - i don't get an error or anything when i start it with the IDE - but i just never see the actual App running in the emulator. The emulator stays just empty for the whole time (that was not the case on Release 2.1).

It is.. kind of sad.. i don't know - the Tizen Documentation looks great on first sight (https://developer.tizen.org). But don't digg deep! There is no info about installation, no info about example Apps (only screenshots, lol). No info about compatible TV's/Firmwares.. No info how the remote connect should work - or why it's not working...

Tizen is just a huge blackbox to me where you're lucky when everything just works - and where things get real nasty real quick when it is not working one time..

Was anybody lucky with this stuff so far?

Ah yeah the install process we were using so far -> get a USB Stick -> make a folder "userwidget" on it -> place your "App.wgt" inside it. Put the stick in the TV, it will install it automatically. Now, nothing happens anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On TV Firmware 1422 it does not work with the pendrive.
I had the same issue, I find an answer here:
http://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen3511/index.html

But before doing what the tutorial says, you need to login with developer account. Go in the menu, smart hub, samsung account, login.
The user (login) is 'develop' and the password is empty.

It is not necessary to do the Set Security Profile that the tutorial shows.

It is working fine to me after doing all the tutorial steps.

Comment: thanks this really helped, especially the tutorial link :) now i'm fighting the last exception: step SDB shell handle failed -.-

Comment: This error I never saw. Sorry, but can't help you with this. If you find a solution, post in here. Thanks.

Comment: I will post it, defenitely - if we ever get an answer from Soel... fun fact, our app is now in the store, released and we're about to go to boston at the brightcove con - but we can't test this damn app, LOL

Answer (score 0):

We had the very same issue, what we did was install it on the tv from the sdk by pairing Tizen IDE with the Samsung TV, creating a NaCli project for samsung TV (the extension of the sdk) and go to the green play button, run configurations, create a new one for "Tizen Device" selecting your project, for the widget file select your .wgt file(the file with your actual app) and target emulator should be your TVs IP (it should be autocompleted since you have the TV already in the connection explorer) then click run and hope for the best, it worked for me and allowed me to install more than one app on a 4k samsung tv.

There are several guides in http://www.samsungdforum.com/ for each step that you may not understand regarding what i explained.

Answer (score 0):

I was in close contact with Samsung support the last few weeks and a i got some clarification material now:

The pendrive solution was disabled by purpose from samsung's side with firmware 1422 - now the only way to deploy an app on your tv is by the network way:

- get a dev-certification, with the button in the SDK IDE (you have to install also the certification tools with update-manager, not only the IDE)
- get a device profile xml (also in this wizard from the IDE)
- put your tv into development mode (open the smart-hub app screen on tv and enter magic sequence "1,2,3,4,5" -> enter the ip of your dev machine)
- now add your tv's ip (you have to be on the same network) in the connection manager of the IDE, you should be able to connect now
- right click the connected tv and choose somewhat "Permit application installation" - this will beam your dev-cert to the tv

After all those steps, you can only right-click your app and choose "run-as -> application" and he will automatically try to deploy the app on the connected tv.

Now, if you're unlucky like me and a strange error saying "can't handle SDB shell execute" appears - then my friend, the story goes on.

Nobody could tell me right now why or what this SDB stuff is, it seems that on some tv's this feature is already turned on, and on some others not. To solve this, you need a so called "private SDK" which only a content manager of samsung could give you.

So you have to go to the Q:A in your samsung dev account and ask them for the contact.. and with some luck you'll get your private SDK which can handle SDB..

I'm still waiting.. (corean new year ^^)